# Write multiple prints in a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I have searched the page for an answer but could only find similar topics that don't exactly touch my specific question.
I'm trying to generate some Dna sequences to play around with biopython and to write all of them into a txt.file.

```
import random as r

def random_dna_sequence(length):
     return ''.join(r.choice('ACTG') for _ in range(length))

for _ in range(15):
     dna = random_dna_sequence(30)
     print (dna)

with open('dna.txt', 'w+') as output:
    output.write(dna)
```

However, this obviously only writes the last line into the file. How can I write all the lines into a file (line by line if necessary) or how can I change the dequence generation code in order to be able to do so?

greetings,
bert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're super close!
You just have to move your for loop within the with block:

```
with open('dna.txt', 'w+') as output:
    for _ in range(15):
        dna = random_dna_sequence(30)
        output.write(dna)
```

Comment: holy cow it works! thanks a lot. there is one last question i would like to ask, though: when i print it every "range" (in this case 15) is shown in a seperate line. how can i get this format into the file (where it is shown as one long string of chars)? usually it's a simple matter of using "/n" properly but in this case i have no idea where to place it.

Comment: @grindbert: write out a `'\n'` after each dna sequence to  your file. Python's `print` does that automatically, but file writing does not

Comment: well, now i'm a bit embarrassed. i used "/n" instead of "\n". thanks a lot!

Comment: and there i am again. once i started messing around with the created file i wondered if i could change the probabilities and quickly found random.choice in numpy. however, i get the error "ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional or an integer". since i'm a complete scrub i can't figure out where multiple dimensions come into play. any suggestions?

Comment: @grindbert: numpy arrays are multidimensional. I'd recommend asking a numpy specific question to get answers from numpy experts